# How to get a certain text from this function?

Tags: php

I'd like to know how to get the text `Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx` from `$cmd = system('ipconfig /all')`.

When I write `$ cmd = system('ipconfig /all')` there is atext displayed in my screen. Even without echoing the `$cmd`. How to remove the text but some portion of the text. I'd like to get `38 chars` after the text `Physical Address`

note: more importantly to get a rid of the displayed text of `system('ipconfig /all')` but still contain it in a variable

Comment: `echo strstr((string)$cmd, 'Physical Address', true);`

Comment: but the whole text is still displayed

Comment: WHat operating system are you working on? I know the `ifconfig` utility, but not `ipconfig`...

Comment: ifconfig is a UNIX based command. ipconfig is winblows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test a bit because i dont know exactly your IPCONFIG results (varies from OS to OS) but here is a very close to what you want:

```
<?php
$command = "ipconfig /all";
$output = shell_exec($command);
$output = explode(PHP_EOL, $output);
$output = $output[0];
$result = explode("Physical Address",$output);
echo substr($result[1],20,17);
?>
```

Keep in mind you may need to change `echo substr($result[1],20,15);` to fit your needs, as it varies depending how many network cards you have etc.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mohammad's answer you could use output buffering.

something like:

```
 ob_start();
 system('ipconfig /all');

 $output = ob_get_clean();

 print_r( $output);
```

should capture everything coming back from the command. You can then manipulate it however you like as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can send second parameter to [***system***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function to get output of command:

```
system('ipconfig /all', $output); //$output is result of command
```

Also you can use [***shell_exec***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function to only return output and not echo by default as below:

```
$output = shell_exec('ipconfig /all');
```

Comment: the text is still displayed even when not echoed

Answer (score 0):

`$val = shell_exec('ipconfig /all');
echo $val;`